# Reference a formula from a different cell, instead of the text of the cell

Tags: excel

DISCLAIMER: I already figured out a work-around, but I'm still convinced there should be a way to do this, and I'd like to know if anyone knows.

I have a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets, and all of them feed two cells into one "Overview sheet".  When I set up the sheet, I foolishly manually entered Cell A, the identifying cell, on the overview spreadsheet, instead of just referencing the cell on the other sheets.  The other cell that gets sent to the Overview Sheet is cell V.

I need to edit a bunch of information (add a second identifying cell) into all of these sheets, and send it to the Overview sheet as well.  Is there a way for me to reference the formula in the second cell, so as to not have to re-enter all of those formulas?

E.G.

```
Sheet1:
A1: Adam Smith
V1: 3565

Sheet2: 
A1: Brett Jones
V1: 4565

Overview Sheet:
A1: Adam Smith
B1: 3565 (through formula '=Sheet1!V1')
A2: Brett Jones 
B2: 4565 ('=Sheet2!V2')
```

---

Is there a function I can use so that I can replace the "V" with an "A", so that I can reference the Sheets without having to re-enter the formula for each individual cell?

My workaround was to move column V to be column B in the individual sheets and then Copy-Paste over, shifting the reference column by one natively.  But I think there should be a way to do this in case you can't move the column for some reason.

Comment: Would Find/Replace work?

Comment: Did you try `indirect`

Comment: I couldn't get indirect to work for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always copy and paste the formula into the new range then use Find ad Replace (Alt+H), to Turn "A" into "V".  if your formulas have more than one instance of "A" in them and you're worried about replacing the wrong things, you can set the find option to "A? " (space intentional, or you can use whatever most commonly follows your cell references). The "?" acts as a wildcard and will find "A1", "A2", ... and "A9".  if your references go into double or triple digits, then "A??? " can be used (again space intentional in case your worried about replacing the wrong thing in something like "=**A234** + **Addr**ess(..." )

However if Find and Replace doesn't work in your situation another work around that I could suggest is

```
=REPLACE(FORMULATEXT("Cell you want to use"),SEARCH("A",FORMULATEXT("Cell you want to use")),1,"V")
```

This should show you exactly what was typed in the formula except the first instance of A was replaced with V.  This should work as long as the cell references are the first thing in the cell.  If they aren't then this method might not work as well as intended.  Another issue with this method is that it results in a string.  you would still need to copy and paste it as a value to result in a usable version of the new formula.

Hopefully this helps answer your question. If not, hopefully someone else might find some use out of this answer to get you the answer you do need.

Comment: That did it!  I don't know why, but in all of my searching for a solution to this I never came across FORMULATEXT as a function.  Thank you!